# vim grepformat for node-jslint output

Tags: vim, jslint

What is the Vim grepformat of the following error output (error output from node-jslint)?

```
static/js/t.js
 #1 Expected 'this' at column 5, not column 3.
    this.JSON2 = {}; // Line 44, Pos 3
 #2 Expected 'use strict' at column 5, not column 3.
    "use strict"; // Line 48, Pos 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim errorformat and jslint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713015/vim-errorformat-and-jslint)

Answer (score 1):

Found answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706966/433662

Used ...

```
setlocal efm=%-P%f,
             \%E%>\ #%n\ %m,%Z%.%#Line\ %l\\,\ Pos\ %c,
             \%-G%f\ is\ OK.,%-Q
```

Plus :make:cw